# Is recursive secret sharing of practical value?

Tags: secret-sharing

[This](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/535.pdf) paper describes recursive secret sharing.  In one of their illustrations, a binary secret of length `L`, along with 3 other binary secrets of lengths shorter than `L`, are split into ternary shares of length `L`.

Any two shares can reconstruct all 4 secrets.

It seems to me there is no advantage in hiding multiple binary secrets in ternary shares, which could not have been gained by concatenating the ternary version of those same secrets and then splitting the resulting, single secret into ternary shares.

Is this correct?  Why or why not?

Comment: Please indicate the figure, the text and location of the claim. Reading through that document is a pain as it is.

Comment: I apologize. It's the first table in the document, on page 2.